# Update panel and scrolling issue

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, updatepanel

I have an update panel which fires when I click a button and I've ran into a problem when the users scrolls after clicking the button.

Basically if the user clicks the button then scrolls down the page the page will then jump back to where the loaded data appears.

I do not want the page to jump back to where the data loads if the user has subsequently scrolled after clicking it.

Any ideas how I can get around this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply the following trick

1. Create a function and bind it to scroll event

   ```
   var yscroll = 0;
   $(document).ready(function(){
   $(window).scroll(function(){
   yscroll=window.pageYOffset;// this will update the latest scroll position  
   })
   });
   ```
2. Bind a function which will fire after the update panel has updated ,on the client side. This can be easly achived by :-
   OnUpdateCompleteClientScript
3. In that function scroll to the last scroll position,where the user was just before the update, like
   window.scrollTo(0, yscroll); //update to last scroll position.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this with either:

```
 <pages maintainScrollPositionOnPostBack="true" />
```

in your web config or:

```
 <%@ Page MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback="true" %>
```

in your page header.